# 英語が残っている: bumped to the homepage

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

Communityユーザーが質問を上げた時に、その旨が質問の下に表示されるようになりましたが、その文章が英語のままです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- bumped to the homepage ([Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/83666311?key=f351b69ecf85717c37709482939efc37))
- This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed. ([Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/101646971?key=84e1a76d3edd1ba168f88bb3d8870c1e))

Transifexでは1週間以上前に翻訳・レビューされていますが、まだ反映されないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

翻訳を更新しました。次回のビルドで適用されます。